# Reading base path from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, jscript

I have a web application created in MVC5/C#

The app uses jscript to call actions from a controller for certain instances.  The problem I am having is that the application is nested deeper on IIS than on my local server.

Local:

```
var urlForModesl = "/ICS_Requisitions/Details";
```

IIS

```
var urlForModesl = "../ICS_Requisitions/Details";
```

Is there anyway I can grab the base path dynamically . . maybe from web.config or something?  So that I don't have to keep switching back and forth.  It's making testing a bit cumbersome, as there are similar situations throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Bundling of Js. If not follow this

```
// create an object of ScriptBundle and 
        // specify bundle name (as virtual path) as constructor parameter 
        ScriptBundle scriptBndl = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap");


        //use Include() method to add all the script files with their paths 
        scriptBndl.Include(
                            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                            "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                          );


        //Add the bundle into BundleCollection
        bundles.Add(scriptBndl);

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Find more details on this link

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/scriptbundle-mvc